# Trouble involving Python

Tags: python

In this code i'm making a loop with numbers until I write "done",after this all numbers that I wrote would be added,counted and after this the average of the numbers.But I've got some problems here

```
    from types import *
    while True:
        number = input("Enter a number")
        junction=[]
        if type(number)is FloatType :
            ju.append(number)
            continue
        elif number=="done":
            break
        else :
            print ("Invalid Input")
            continue

    print (sum(junction))
    print (len(junction))
    print (sum(junction)/len(junction))
```

Comment: What are your problems? Explain please

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using a `try/except` block instead (Also: you should create the empty list *outside* your `while` loop):

```
x = []

while True:
    a = input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        x.append(int(a))
    except ValueError:
        if a == 'done':
            break
        else:
            print ("Invalid Input")
            continue

print ('Results')
print (sum(x))
print (len(x))
print (sum(x)/len(x))
```

Also note that `input` is for python3 and if you are using python2, you should use `raw_input` instead, for the same effect.

Comment: Looks good, but `raw_input`, will need to be used instead of `input` (else it'll fail on 'done').

Comment: @jedwards, Actually, the OP is using python3 in which there is no `raw_input` and `input` is python3's equivalent for it

Comment: If he's using Python 3, I agree, but I didn't/don't see any explicit note saying that -- it is indicated by the divisions though.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the code will run on, say, 2.7 without an exception until you type 'done'.  Him running 2.7 with 3 syntax could also be a source of issues.

Comment: @jedwards, Ah I see what you mean. I have included the warning in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I presume you're right about Python 3 given the divisions, but the added warning may help (or help future visitors): +1

Answer (score 1):

The very simple answer is that you are resetting the `junction` list *inside* your loop, every time. So it will be empty almost all the time, specifically when you enter `"done"` to quit.

Move it to the top of your program; above the `while` statement, and it should work better for you.

(Also, you don't need to use `continue`, since the only way for the loop *not* to continue is for it to hit the `break` statement. In all other cases, the loop will continue on its own.)

```
from types import *
junction=[]
while True:
    number = input("Enter a number")
    if type(number)is FloatType :
        junction.append(number)
    elif number=="done":
        break
    else:
        print ("Invalid Input")

print (sum(junction))
print (len(junction))
print (sum(junction)/len(junction))
```